# Breathe (Doxygen to Sphinx) AttributeError: 'pending_xref' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Tags: python, doxygen, python-sphinx, attributeerror

I wanted to migrate documentation from Doxygen to Sphinx, I found out that Breathe should be a good tool, but I have faced a problem and I cannot move forward.

When I try to

```
make html
```

I get an error:

```
# Sphinx version: 1.5.1
# Python version: 2.7.12 (CPython)
# Docutils version: 0.13.1 release
# Jinja2 version: 2.8
# Last messages:
#   making output directory...
#   loading pickled environment...
#   not yet created
#   loading intersphinx inventory from http://docs.python.org/objects.inv...
#   intersphinx inventory has moved: http://docs.python.org/objects.inv -> https://docs.python.org/2/objects.inv
#   building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
#   building [html]: targets for 2 source files that are out of date
#   updating environment:
#   2 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
#   reading sources... [ 50%] index
# Loaded extensions:
#   sphinx.domains.cpp (builtin) from /home/tango/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/domains/cpp.pyc
#   sphinx.builders.applehelp (builtin) from /home/tango/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/builders/applehelp.pyc
#   sphinx.directives (builtin) from /home/tango/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/directives/__init__.pyc
#   sphinx.builders.changes (builtin) from /home/tango/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/builders/changes.pyc
#   sphinx.builders.websupport (builtin) from /home/tango/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/builders/websupport.pyc
#   sphinx.domains.c (builtin) from /home/tango/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/domains/c.pyc
#   sphinx.builders.dummy (builtin) from /home/tango/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/builders/dummy.pyc
#   sphinx.builders.texinfo (builtin) from /home/tango/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/builders/texinfo.pyc
#   sphinx.builders.epub (builtin) from /home/tango/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/builders/epub.pyc
#   sphinx.builders.linkcheck (builtin) from /home/tango/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/builders/linkcheck.pyc
#   sphinx.ext.viewcode (1.5.1) from /home/tango/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/ext/viewcode.pyc
#   sphinx.domains.std (builtin) from /home/tango/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/domains/std.pyc
#   sphinx.directives.other (builtin) from /home/tango/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/directives/other.pyc
#   sphinx.builders.epub3 (builtin) from /home/tango/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/builders/epub3.pyc
#   sphinx.domains.javascript (builtin) from /home/tango/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/domains/javascript.pyc
#   sphinx.directives.code (builtin) from /home/tango/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/directives/code.pyc
#   breathe (4.4.0) from /home/tango/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/breathe/__init__.pyc
#   sphinx.ext.autodoc (1.5.1) from /home/tango/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc.pyc
#   sphinx.ext.intersphinx (1.5.1) from /home/tango/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/ext/intersphinx.pyc
#   alabaster (0.7.9) from /home/tango/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/alabaster/__init__.pyc
#   sphinx.builders.text (builtin) from /home/tango/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/builders/text.pyc
#   sphinx.builders.qthelp (builtin) from /home/tango/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/builders/qthelp.pyc
#   sphinx.roles (builtin) from /home/tango/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/roles.pyc
#   sphinx.builders.htmlhelp (builtin) from /home/tango/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/builders/htmlhelp.pyc
#   sphinx.directives.patches (builtin) from /home/tango/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/directives/patches.pyc
#   sphinx.ext.ifconfig (1.5.1) from /home/tango/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/ext/ifconfig.pyc
#   sphinx.builders.latex (builtin) from /home/tango/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/builders/latex.pyc
#   sphinx.builders.html (builtin) from /home/tango/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/builders/html.pyc
#   sphinx.builders.devhelp (builtin) from /home/tango/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/builders/devhelp.pyc
#   sphinx.builders.gettext (builtin) from /home/tango/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/builders/gettext.pyc
#   sphinx.builders.xml (builtin) from /home/tango/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/builders/xml.pyc
#   sphinx.builders.manpage (builtin) from /home/tango/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/builders/manpage.pyc
#   sphinx.domains.rst (builtin) from /home/tango/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/domains/rst.pyc
#   sphinx.domains.python (builtin) from /home/tango/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/domains/python.pyc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tango/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/cmdline.py", line 296, in main
```

(...)

```
File "/home/tango/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/breathe/renderer/sphinxrenderer.py", line 1156, in render
  result = method(self, node)
File "/home/tango/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/breathe/renderer/sphinxrenderer.py", line 1076, in visit_templateparamlist
  nodelist.extend(self.render(item))
File "/home/tango/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/breathe/renderer/sphinxrenderer.py", line 1156, in render
  result = method(self, node)
File "/home/tango/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/breathe/renderer/sphinxrenderer.py", line 986, in visit_param
  if first_node.startswith(keyword + ' '):
AttributeError: 'pending_xref' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```